# Linked List not being Modified

Tags: c, linked-list

I am attempting to add a node to the beginning of a linked list, but the list is not being modified in one of my functions, but is being modified in the other...

Here is my function to insert at the beginning.

```
llist* insert_beginning(llist *list, gymnast_info *g) {                         
     llist *new = (llist *)malloc(sizeof(llist));                                
     new->g = g;                                                                 
     new->next = list;                                                           
     list = new;                                                                 
     return list;                                                                
 }
```

In this function, the linked list is being modified correctly

```
llist *add_sorted_name(gymnast_info *ginfo, llist *head) {
    llist *accu = head;
    while (accu) {
        // Beginning of list                                                         
        if (strcasecmp(accu->g->lastname, ginfo->lastname) > 0
                && accu == head) {
            return insert_beginning(head, ginfo);
        }
......
    }
}
```

However, in this one, it is not. It returns the correct list, but it does not modify the inputted list. I have no idea why.

```
llist *add_sorted_country(gymnast_info *ginfo, llist *head) {
    llist *accu = head;
    int country = ginfo->country;
    while (accu) {
        //Beginning of the list                                                      
        if (accu->g->country >= country && accu == head) {
            return insert_beginning(head, ginfo);
        }
        .......
    }
}
```

Comment: `new->next = list;` - you are creating a *circular list* (which is fine -- every node is a data node) However, when modifying the list where the 1st node can change, you must pass the *address of* the list as a function parameter (e.g.  `llist **head`) because if the 1st node changes -- the list address changes. Please provide a [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the code would be OK, if the caller of `insert_beginning` checks the return value and acts accordingly (like with `realloc`). The other two functions kind of do this, but we don't see how they are called, so the error may be there.

Comment: There is a lot we can't tell because we don't have the code, but by passing `llist *head` in `add_sorted...` each `add_sorted...` function receives a **copy of** `head` with its very own -- and very different address. (the address stored within is the same, but the address of `head` isn't) So if `head` is ever used as the address of a pointer in the list, the list will not be contiguous. (now if `llist` is a pointer to a dummy node -- then you are fine)

Answer (score 0):

Currently `insert_beginning` is only changing the pointing address of a
**local** copy of the pointer. The caller does not see the change. But because
you return the new head, the caller **must** check the return value and replace
the head of the list.

`add_sorted_name` and `add_sorted_country` are kind of doing that, because they
are just returning the new head right away. What we don't see is how the caller
of `add_sorted_name` and `add_sorted_country` is dealing with the result. If
they do:

```
add_sorted_country(ginfo, head);
do_something_with(head);
```

then you won't see any change of the head, because you've ignored it. You would
need to call them like this (similar as a `realloc` call):

```
llist *tmp = add_sorted_country(ginfo, head);
if(tmp == NULL)
{
    // error handling
    // do not continue
}

head = tmp; // assigning possible new head
```

Such an API is fine, but you **have** to make sure that you always check the
return value of the functions. This might be the problem in the first place.

Another way to do this (and perhaps safer) would be to pass a pointer to the pointer to the head and let the
functions that change the head, change it through the double pointer.

```
int insert_beginning(llist **list, gymnast_info *g) {
    if(list == NULL)
        return 0;

    llist *new = calloc(1, sizeof *new);                                
    new->g = g;                                                                 
    new->next = *list;
    *list = new; // setting 'new' as new head
    return 1;                                                                
}
```

Then `add_sorted_name` should look like this

```
int add_sorted_name(gymnast_info *ginfo, llist **head) {
   if(head == NULL)
       return 0;

   llist *accu = *head;
   while (accu) {
       // Beginning of list                                                         
       if (strcasecmp(accu->g->lastname, ginfo->lastname) > 0
       && accu == head) {

           return insert_beginning(head, ginfo);
       }
   ......
   }
}
```